# Protractor setup example is not working

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am running the example posted on [github](http://angular.github.io/protractor/#/) for protractor.  When I run the example I get error:

> NoSuchElementError: No element found using locator: by.model("todoText")

I am using the same settings listed on the website:

### todo-spec.js:

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoText')).sendKeys('write a protractor test');
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todos'));
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write a protractor test');
  });
});
```

### conf.js

```
exports.config = {
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  specs: ['test/e2e/app/todo-spec.js']
};
```

I tried changing the value to `todoList`.  This also failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the value for ng-model is todoList.todoText on the angular website so...

```
element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write a protractor test');
```

and probably

```
var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
```

Comment: It's really silly that the first example on Protractor depends on a specific angular app on AngularJS.org. There's a joke in there about the value of testing.

Comment: What's even sillier is an intro example covering how to test Angular is itself broken.  I've had many problems with Angular in terms of broken/bad documentation.  As a newbie thus far I am entirely frustrated with the framework as a whole.  This answer gets me past the first error only to open up 2 more.

Comment: Doesn't exactly inspire confidence in Protractor.js . . .

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of todo-spec.js that works:

### todo-spec.js

```
describe('angularjs homepage todo list', function() {
  it('should add a todo', function() {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');

    element(by.model('todoList.todoText')).sendKeys('write a protractor test');//correction
    element(by.css('[value="add"]')).click();

    var todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));//correction
    expect(todoList.count()).toEqual(3);
    expect(todoList.get(2).getText()).toEqual('write a protractor test');
  });
});
```